# remove redundant function in javascript

Tags: javascript, merge

i have some little javascript library which can be loaded separately and work without any dependency.
now i want to merge some of them into a single js file. the problem is that every of them has some part in common( some helper function).
Is there some tools i can use to merge these file and remove the redundant code?

Comment: Ctrl-F in accompany with Ctrl-X, Ctrl-C, and Ctrl-V ... imo

Comment: i dont think so, you should have considered this before building your library.

Comment: @Praveen Prasad -- yes, all sorts of tasks would be easier if everybody could either see the future or change the past.  Since the OP cannot do those, he's looking for a re-factoring tool.

Comment: @malvolio: what type of tool should i suggest use ctrl+x, ctrl-c, ctrl-v, like Joseph has suggested. I have  never heard any tool that would remove two functions(merge into 1) with different names and does same thing.

Comment: @Praveen Prasad -- well, there's [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), but I don't think its refactoring tools work with Javascript.  My actual point was not that there was an answer better than Joseph's, but that there were few answers worse than yours, scolding the OP for not having foresight better than your hindsight.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA (and its JS cousin, Webstorm) is actually quite good with refactoring Javascript. It is not going to help you remove redundant code however. It does help with detecting unused functions, globals etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the redundancy is duplicated code (exact copies or copies with modifications), our [JavaScript CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) can help find the duplicated code and suggest the essence of the subroutines you need to remove the duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you have redundant code I would never trust a program to compile them together, especially if I needed to edit it in the future (cause lets face it, even if we think we won't, you will)

Personally I would take a day to go over everything and rework it so that everything run smoothly and most importantly there are no redundancies. I will often rewrite things 2-3 times when it is a larger script and if I feel it can be better.